# How to tell where recent ssh sessions originated from?

Tags: ssh, logs, login

I know that sometimes when I login to systems they print out where the most recent ssh session originated from (usually an ip address or hostname). How can I lookup where some of the most recent ssh logins from my username originated from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Unix command called `last` that will list the last times and sources of all the logins to the system. Not all logins make it into the log `last` looks at. Only logins that end up creating a `wtmp` entry have that privilege. On Fedora 17 these logins end up being logged in a file named `/var/log/wtmp`.

Generally most things that create some kind of interactive terminal session generally log to `wtmp`. Several commands that create such interactive sessions have options for whether or not to create a `wtmp` entry. For example `xterm` has the `-ls` option to force a `wtmp` entry to be written even if `xterm` is started to run a command with `-e`.